# temporarily disable kerberos ticket cache in python

Tags: python, linux, kerberos

I am in the middle of coding some automation in python.
The issue is that half the code must use a valid Kerberos ticket.
Then the other half must temporarily disable Kerberos ticket and run. 
Now I do not want to use kdestroy, since the code may be reused and will need a valid Kerberos ticket all over again. 
This process would be very simple if I code re-initializing of the ticket at every iteration, but auto kinit is not allowed.

So, the user must manually initialize the ticket and run the code multiple times; each time, the code will use a valid Kerberos ticket and then somehow pause or disable ticket but does not destroy it.
At the next iteration it re-enables the Kerberos ticket and repeat.

How do I "disable" and "enable" Kerberos tickets?

Comment: Read this [Using the Python Kerberos Module](http://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_kerberos.html)

Comment: Read this Section [DISABLED](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-kerberos)

Comment: `export KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/path/to/specific-file-name-to-use-as-ticket-cache`